# Is there a way to sync Windows Sticky Notes with Google Keep?

Tags: sync, sticky-notes

Was wondering if there was a way for everything that I put on a Sticky Note on Windows, it would automatically make the same note in my Google Keep account.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you might have found out a solution for this. But if you haven't yet like me. You can try [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki).

It'll appear just like the sticky notes but is a chrome window.
[image]

Tip: You can pin it in the taskbar and open it anytime.

I find it much helpful.

[Source](http://www.rawinfopages.com/tips/2014/06/abandon-sticky-notes-and-put-google-keep-on-the-desktop/)